# C# LocalDb encoding issue - missing polish characters on updating database

Tags: c#, sql-server, encoding, localdb

**Context**

I'm currently working on small quick project, which involves a service-based database. This is VS C# app with a SQL Server `.mdf` database file in LocalDb with only one table - personal data. All it needs to do is create a print with labels with data from the database. I created everything with VS Community 2015, including the database.

**Problem**

However, I'm stuck. Everything works without problems, but whenever I put some data with Polish letters into TextBoxes like `ł ą ś ć ź` and save it, the DataGridViewer displays it as `l a s c z`.

I guess there must be an easy trick to get it done. Previously, when I made a similar app with SQL Server Compact database there was no such issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the actual content of the database?

Comment: Database is filled with temporary 3 records. Every record has fields like 'name', 'surname', 'personal_id', 'street' etc. When you add a new record and fill TextBox (that responds to street field) with "Łomnickiego" it is being saved to database as "Lomnickiego".

Comment: I understand that the database holds the value "Lomnickiego" instead of "Łomnickiego". Can you edit your post and include the code that saves the data into the db?